# How do I source files on a custom html tag?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, src, innertext

I am trying to create my own computer language but can't get the src attribute to work. Is there a way to get the source code to "paste" to the inner text of the element?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <h1 id="p"></h1>
    <space-lang src="Testing.txt">
    
</space-lang>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="space.js">
    </script>
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: My language tag is <space-lang>

Comment: _"I am trying to create my own computer language"_ - please elaborate

Comment: Your HTML is invalid: you can't have a `<h1>` inside `<head>`. I also don't think you can use [Custom HTML Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) inside `<head>` either.

Comment: I am creating a compiler/lexer that reads txt files and translates them to my "space" language but I can't seem to read "source files" for some reason. It doesn't show any errors but doesn't read them either.

Comment: Show us your `space.js` script.

Comment: I tried it's to big

Comment: Your question lies in `space.js`. Don't post the whole thing, but please post a [mre].

Comment: function prepare(){
var content=document.querySelector("space-lang")
content.style.display="none"
c=content.innerText
var testing=content.getAttribute("src") 
testing=testing.toString()
console.log(testing)
fetch(testing).then(data=>c=data.text())
console.log(c)
var code=c.split(" ")
for(var i=0;i<=code.length-1;i++){
    if(code[i]==="addH1"){
        var t=code[i+2].split("_")
        code[i+2]=""
        for(var s=0;s<=t.length-1;s++){
            code[i+2]=code[i+2]+" "+t[s]
        }
        addH1(code[i+1],code[i+2],code[i+3])
    }

Comment: It's missing some brackets but this is the attribute checking

Comment: `c.split(" ")` <-- This is not a good way to build a lexer...

Comment: It's the only way I know lol everything else I'm like ‍

Comment: anyway I tried xml requests and fetch neither worked one would not pull up anything and the other ran into cors errors